# Why didn't bundler install the dependency?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

My understanding of bundler is that when you add a Gem to the Gemfile, bundler will automatically install all its dependencies when you run `bundle install`.

I am creating a gem. In my gemspec, I specified the following requirements:

```
spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.7"
spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
spec.add_development_dependency "eventmachine", "~> 1.0.4"
spec.add_development_dependency "em-synchrony"
spec.add_development_dependency "rspec"
```

Bundler completed all the installations just fine. When I look at Gem.lock, I notice the following:

```
...
em-synchrony (1.0.5)
  eventmachine (>= 1.0.0.beta.1)
...
```

Notice no MySQL dependency for em-synchrony. When I launch irb, and I require my gem, I get the following error:

```
> require 'my_gem'
RuntimeError: Missing EM-Synchrony dependency: gem install mysql2
```

Why didn't bundler install the mysql2 gem automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`em-synchrony` does not depend on `mysql2`. It is merely a supported client, one of several: https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony#em-synchrony

Indeed, looking at em-synchrony's gemspec reveals only one dependency `eventmachine`: https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony/blob/master/em-synchrony.gemspec

It is, however, a [development dependency](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony/blob/master/Gemfile) of em-synchrony as listed in the development group in its Gemfile. These dependencies won't get installed for you.

You'll have to manually include `mysql2` yourself.